# How to alter axis limits for a scatter after creating a figure in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to create a plot of an NFL field and then put a scatterplot over it. Here is my code for the field (just copy paste all of this. This isn't where my question lies):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl


# Create figure
fig, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

# Set field dimensions
plt.xlim(0, 120)  # Field length including endzones
plt.ylim(0, 53.3)  # field width

# Set field color green
ax.set_facecolor('#79af75')
ax.set_alpha(0.5)

# Print lines
for i in range(0, 120, 10):
    plt.axvline(i, color='white', linewidth=3, alpha=0.4, zorder=1)
    if i == 10 or i == 110:  # Make endzone lines
        plt.axvline(i, color='white', linewidth=5, alpha=0.4, zorder=1)

# Paint numbers
yds_from_sideline = 12
for i in range(10, 50, 10):
    plt.text(i+10, 53.3-yds_from_sideline, str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)
    plt.text(110-i, 53.3-yds_from_sideline,  str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)

    plt.text(i+10, yds_from_sideline, str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')
    plt.text(110-i, yds_from_sideline, str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')

# Paint 50 yard line numbers
plt.text(60, 53.3-yds_from_sideline, str(50), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)
plt.text(60, yds_from_sideline, str(50), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')

# Print something in the endzones

plt.text(5, 26.5, 'Vikings', color='#4F2683', fontsize=30, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=90)
plt.text(115, 26.5, 'Opponent', color='black', fontsize=30, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=270)


# Fix the aspect ratio (optional)
plt.gca().set_aspect(1)

# Display the figure
plt.show()
```

If you run this, it should work great! Now, I have the dataset I want to plot over it. Here is a sample of it:

```
data

  posteam   yardline_100    epa
0   MIN         1.0       0.343304
1   MIN         2.0       0.340690
2   MIN         3.0       0.128643
3   MIN         4.0       0.747664
4   MIN         5.0      -0.190321
5   MIN         6.0       0.265953
6   MIN         7.0      -0.362923
7   MIN         8.0      -0.684526
8   MIN         9.0      -0.107560
9   MIN         10.0      0.263269
10  MIN         11.0     -0.042605
11  MIN         12.0      0.126719
12  MIN         13.0     -0.531782
13  MIN         14.0     -0.329170
14  MIN         15.0      0.608268
```

I tried to add the following code to the field plot, but it did not work out.

The added code:

```
plt.title('The gridiron', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('EPA', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Yardline', fontsize=12)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-5, 6,1))

ax.scatter(x='yardline_100',y='epa',data=data)
```

The whole thing and output:

```
# Create figure
fig, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

# Set field dimensions
plt.xlim(0, 120)  # Field length including endzones
plt.ylim(0, 53.3)  # field width

# Set field color green
ax.set_facecolor('#79af75')
ax.set_alpha(0.5)

# Print lines
for i in range(0, 120, 10):
    plt.axvline(i, color='white', linewidth=3, alpha=0.4, zorder=1)
    if i == 10 or i == 110:  # Make endzone lines
        plt.axvline(i, color='white', linewidth=5, alpha=0.4, zorder=1)

# Paint numbers
yds_from_sideline = 12
for i in range(10, 50, 10):
    plt.text(i+10, 53.3-yds_from_sideline, str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)
    plt.text(110-i, 53.3-yds_from_sideline,  str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)

    plt.text(i+10, yds_from_sideline, str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')
    plt.text(110-i, yds_from_sideline, str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')

# Paint 50 yard line numbers
plt.text(60, 53.3-yds_from_sideline, str(50), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)
plt.text(60, yds_from_sideline, str(50), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')

# Print something in the endzones

plt.text(5, 26.5, 'Vikings', color='#4F2683', fontsize=30, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=90)
plt.text(115, 26.5, 'Opponent', color='black', fontsize=30, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=270)

# Just showing how to set titles and labels
plt.title('The gridiron', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('EPA', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Yardline', fontsize=12)

plt.title('The gridiron', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('EPA', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Yardline', fontsize=12)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-5, 6,1))

ax.scatter(x='yardline_100',y='epa',data=data)


# Fix the aspect ratio (optional)
plt.gca().set_aspect(1)

# Display the figure
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I would really like to do is scale the axis so -5 is at the bottom and 5 is at the top of the y axis instead of having the -5 to 5 range scrunched at the bottom. Furthermore, I would like to move the x-axis over 10 units while in the same manner. That is, I would like to scatters to start at X=10 instead of X=0. If you need further clarification please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I've first scaled `ylim` to your wanted range (-5,5), then scaled the yard values for `plt.text()` from range(0,53.3) to range(-5,5), adjusting the top/bottom values in `plt.text()` accordingly (from 53.3 to 5, from 0 to -5). Finally changed `ax.scatter()` to directly reference your data columns, so to offset on x-axis just added a value of 10. Also, dropped `set_aspect(1)`.

This way you don't create an overly large figure at the beginning, which you then have to wrangle into submission.

**Code** (changes a preceded by comment `# CHANGES HERE !!!`**:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

# Create figure
fig, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

# Set field dimensions
plt.xlim(0, 120)  # Field length including endzones

# CHANGES HERE !!!
# set ylim respective to your data
plt.ylim(-5, 5)  # field width

# Set field color green
ax.set_facecolor('#79af75')
ax.set_alpha(0.5)

# Print lines
for i in range(0, 120, 10):
    plt.axvline(i, color='white', linewidth=3, alpha=0.4, zorder=1)
    if i == 10 or i == 110:  # Make endzone lines
        plt.axvline(i, color='white', linewidth=5, alpha=0.4, zorder=1)

# Paint numbers
yds_from_sideline = 12
for i in range(10, 50, 10):
#   CHANGES HERE !!!
#   change y values because ylim has changed (top-ylim - yds_from_sideline translated to scale of ylim)
    plt.text(i+10, 5-10*(yds_from_sideline/53.3), str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)
    plt.text(110-i, 5-10*(yds_from_sideline/53.3),  str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)

    plt.text(i+10, -5 + 10*(yds_from_sideline/53.3), str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')
    plt.text(110-i, -5 + 10*(yds_from_sideline/53.3), str(i), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')

# Paint 50 yard line numbers
# CHANGES HERE !!!
# change y values here as well
plt.text(60, 5-10*(yds_from_sideline/53.3), str(50), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=180)
plt.text(60, -5+10*(yds_from_sideline/53.3), str(50), color='white', fontsize=20, verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center')

# Print something in the endzones

plt.text(5, 0, 'Vikings', color='#4F2683', fontsize=30, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=90)
plt.text(115, 0, 'Opponent', color='black', fontsize=30, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center', rotation=270)

# Just showing how to set titles and labels
plt.title('The gridiron', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('EPA', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Yardline', fontsize=12)

plt.title('The gridiron', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('EPA', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Yardline', fontsize=12)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-5, 6,1))

# CHANGES HERE !!!
# increase x by 10 to start at x = 10
ax.scatter(x=data['yardline_100']+10,y=data['epa'])



# # Fix the aspect ratio (optional)
# plt.gca().set_aspect(1)

# Display the figure
plt.show()
```

**Output** (using your example data)**:**

[image]